# How to edit a big shapefile online?

Tags: gis, spatialite

I have a big shape file (about 1GB) and I need to display and update data from this file with
an online map (mapbox).
As I understand I need to convert this shapefile into some DB (Spatialite? PostGIS)
and then query it by map BBOX to display by parts.
What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thats a huge topic and depends very much on the usecase. If you want to dive deeper into the topic I would recommend this [articel](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/dynamic-vector-tiles-from-postgis). It describes the underlaying theory and gives a working example for a SQL-Query. For me, it was sufficient to get going with a viable prototype. I think Postgres (with it's Postgis extension) would be a good choice since the data can be directly served as mvt.

Answer (score 0):

I found this site very useful for displaying GeoJson on the fly, it usually copes well with large data, failing that you can import it too. https://geojson.io